# onPostExecute is executing before completion of doInBackground

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-studio

I am trying to execute some server side functionality in doInBackground() method and by depending on the result of server I have to execute few steps, I 've written them in onPostExecute() but for me onPostExecute() is executing before completion of doInBackground()

```
protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
   final String ccode = params[0];
   final String mobile = params[1];
   final String img= params[2];


   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                        respon = response;
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), respon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                },
                                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                    }
                                }){
                            @Override
                            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                params.put(KEY_MOB,mobile);
                                params.put(KEY_COUNTRY,ccode);
                                params.put("pic",img);
                                return params;
                            }

                        };
                        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
                        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                        String[] s = {params[0],params[1],params[2]};
                        return s;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "22222", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++***************"+respon);
                        if(respon.equals("success")) {
                            ob.register_user(m_n,cntry,nme,p_pic);
                            Intent h = new Intent(User_detais.this, home.class);
                            startActivity(h);
                            finish();
                        } else{

                            android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                            builder1.setMessage("Please Check your Data Connection and try again.");
                            builder1.setCancelable(true);

                            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                    "Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                            android.app.AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                            alert11.show();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're using Volley in `doInBackground`. Volley's Requests are themselves asynchronous and do not block the UI. So, once the code in `doInBackground` is run, it does not wait for the request to complete.

What you should do instead is shun this `AsyncTask` and simply do whatever you want to so in `onResponse` and `onErrorResponse`.